# Attempting to control a Raspberry Pi running Kodi with a LG RF remote

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, remote, kodi, cec-client

I'm running a Kodi application within a Raspberry Pi4 connected to an HDMI port on an LG TV with an RF remote.  The problem is that I'm not able to control the Kodi application using the LG's RF remote.

On the Kodi side, I've verified that Kodi is accepting CEC commands when I connect the Pi to a Samsung TV with an IR remote.  It works as expected on the the Samsung TV.

On the LG TV side, I've enabled Simplink within the TV and gone through all related options without success.

At this point, I'm stuck.  Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Regards and thanks.

Rob

Comment: Have you confirmed it actually works without the Pi in the chain, another device doing that controlling of it. If the LG has a broken implementation of the "standard" it may not work with something which expects that correct behaviour. You have already confirmed a device will accept the commands from the Pi, so it does send them correctly, if the second does not get them then it is the broken one.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something in the way this CEC works...

Comment: You are not missing a thing, the LG is if my suspicions are correct and it has bad implementation of it in the TV. It is supposed to be a standard interface, if it works on one device the next should work too, if the next does not doing the exact same as the first then the device is broken in its support of the standard. Would not be the first and I highly doubt the last time I have seen that. My USB keyboard is supposed to work with a Pi too, plug it in and it will not boot...

Comment: I checked with LG tech support and they acknowledge that their version of the CEC standard does not work with all devices and it certainly won't properly work with anything that does not display a Simplink label.  Sounds more like a propitiatory command set rather than an industry standard to me.  Frustrating as I bought the LG TV with the plan to use that specific feature.  I'll have to figure out the best way to control the Raspberry Pi/Kodi.  My short term fix is to use a wireless keyboard/mouse... not ideal but it does the job.  Thanks to HappyTux for your suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome, too bad my suspicions proved correct. Manufacturers are such idiots at times, they probably saved ten cents a unit doing that. Resulting in more than few angry customers who quite rightly feel they have been ripped of by their stupidity.